# How to change grid view item height depends on view's height?

Tags: android, gridview

I want to draw dynamic small squares like 8x9 or 3x2 etc.

this grid item's height and width must be equal and it should be changed depends on view's size.

How can I do this ? any advice or sample code please ?

Answer (score 0):

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    //if you need three fix imageview in width
    int devicewidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels / 3;

    //if you need 4-5-6 anything fix imageview in height
    int deviceheight = displaymetrics.heightPixels / 4;

    holder.image_view.getLayoutParams().width = devicewidth;

    //if you need same height as width you can set devicewidth in holder.image_view.getLayoutParams().height
    holder.image_view.getLayoutParams().height = deviceheight;

holder.image_view.getLayoutParams().height = devicewidth;
```

use display metric to get the size of the device screen and you can use the width and height of the screen to structure the width & height of view